# Juno, sound work but headphone does not (alienware m17xr4)

Tags: release-juno, sound

I'm just new to Elementary OS,

After install Juno, my laptop speaker work fine, but when I connect my headphone, there is no sound in headphone but the sound go through speaker as normal.

I has tried something (PulseAudio Volume Control) but it does not work out.

Below is my sound setting img and my alsa link: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=10ef87553a781ec4fab8852389fe7acc1db25ac6

Thanks for any help!

[image: Settings/Sound]

---

Edit: solution found

In terminal, enter the command `alsamixer`

An ASCI UI will open, use the arrow keys to find the item: "HP/speaker Auto Detect". it will say "Off" next to it.

Press M and the "Off" tag will disappear.

Re-plug your headphones.

Answer (score 1):

Alienware laptops generally have "different" spec sound chips (as well as all sorts of other "gaming" optimisations) and so it is likely that the default sound drivers might not work. You might want to look at the drivers available and see if there is something that might work. A quick on-line search throws up this lot: https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/alienware-m17x-r4/drivers